# Using anise seed instead of star anise

Tags: substitutions, spices, soup

I have wanted to make Vietnamese pho bo for a while, and a simple recipe I found calls for 6 star anise. I couldn't find this, and instead bought some anise seed since I read anise seed is used as a substitute for it, sometimes. I'm wondering if a) the anise seed will work for pho and if so, b) how much anise seed should be added when the recipe called for 6 star anise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I asked a few friends, and one linked me this website:

http://www.foodsubs.com/SpiceUniv.html

It says 1 tsp. of seeds for every 2 star anise (crushed).